# Error al hacer Fetch en JavaScript (React)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, fetch

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en **React** que está casi acabado, pero ahora estoy conectando la parte del React con un servidor backend que tengo de NodeJS.

La porción de código es sencila, pero me está dando **problemas**.

```
fetch ("http://[IpDelServer]/printAbuelos")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

*El error que me da es el siguiente:*

> Failed to fetch
>
> TypeError: Failed to fetch
> at ResidenciaPage (http://localhost:3000/main.f57f2a12c43205a20c5e.hot-update.js:233:3)
> at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25378:22)
> at updateFunctionComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28260:24)
> at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29972:20)
> at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34923:18)
> at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34192:16)
> at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34115:9)
> at renderRootSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34088:11)
> at performSyncWorkOnRoot (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33780:24)
> at flushSyncCallbacks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:21810:26)

Y lo he intentado todo, pero siempre da un error en el fetch, pero la consulta en el servidor es exitosa.

Comment: Sí, pero sigue igual. Ha sido error mío al copiar.

Answer (score 1):

Vale, está solucionado.
Solo hay que añadirle Cors al servidor.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

// Habilita CORS para todas las rutas
app.use(cors());

// Resto de la configuración de tu servidor...

// Ruta de ejemplo
app.get('/printAbuelos', (req, res) => {
    // Lógica de tu ruta
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Servidor escuchando en el puerto ${PORT}`);
});
```